# Read audio output from a specific source using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I want to read audio from a desktop application (for eg Spotify) using node but can't seem to figure out how. I know it's possible to read input from your microphone/general desktop audio but I was wondering whether it would be possible to **select** which desktop app you want to record audio from.

Comment: maybe it should be better listening to the output channel

Comment: It would depend on the os and the sound layer, and probably the audio mixer.